# GCP Logging - Identify Unusual Traffic

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-logging

I recently noticed some unusual traffic on my Google Cloud SQL instance.

Can you please help me identify the source of this traffic?(Attached image)

Interestingly, I get around 40 Hits(All 'password authentication failed') in a 15 minute span everyday and then nothing. The exact log does not contain any IP or other source information so I am curious if there was another way I could find info on the source.

P.S It is not due to anything I have scheduled/automated.

[image: Logs Explorer Sample]

Comment: Please update your question with more details about your setup, do you allow connections from the Internet etc. The more details the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured Cloud SQL instance to have a public IPv4 address? if so the connection can be using:

- the public IP and coming from the adresses or the ranges you configured in `Cloud SQL Instances > Overview > Connections > Authorized networks`
- the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy but the it must has the at least the `cloudsql.instances.connect` permission

If only the private IP is configured on your instance, you can only connect from within the same network as your instance (*so it's less worrying*).

Unfortunately the audit logs for "cloudsql.instances.connect" that can show the ip address of the caller, shows only when the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy

- has the permission mentioned above and succeeds to autneticate
- dont have the permission and show the `Not authorized to access resource` log message
  and it's not your case